# Finish extension (avoid dialplan to silently continue in the next priority of another extension)

Tags: asterisk

I have run into a strange behaviour:

```
[ctx-test]

exten => h,1,NoOp(*** hangup ***)

exten => _.,1,NoOp(*** ${EXTEN} ***)
 same => n,...
 same => n,...
 same => n,Hangup()
```

Strangely, the `h` extension continues on the priority 2 of the extension `_.`. Maybe this is caused by the use of `same`? How can I make sure that an extension is really ending, something like:

```
exten => h,1,NoOp(*** hangup ***)
 same => n,RellyEndHere()
```

For subroutines there is the `Return()` application, but this can not be used generally in contexts. Is there any application to finish processing the extension in the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the use of the `_.` pattern.

Asterisk book warns against using this pattern due to the fact it catches the special one-letter extensions.